# Using eso-pic to add a watermark text in front of everything

Tags: pdftex, watermark, eso-pic, tinytex

I'm trying to get a very simple watermark/draft text spanning my latex file pages.

I was using `draftwatermark` package but after I needed it to stay on top of some plot images I have, so i tried `xwatermark` but it doesn't work on latest TinyTeX version anymore

Now I'm trying to make it work with eso-pic by just copying examples online, this is what I have so far :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}        
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}   
\usepackage{moreverb}                
\usepackage{url}                      
\usepackage{amssymb}                  
\usepackage[pdftex]{lscape}           
\usepackage{longtable}                
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{lastpage}                
\usepackage{parskip}                  
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}       
\usepackage{hyphenat}                 
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{xcolor}
    
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
  \AtTextCenter{%
    \raisebox{3\baselineskip}{%
      \rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{%
        \color{red} Preview
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
```

So far what I'm missing :

1. The text should be bigger but without changing the fontsize of my whole document, how can I do this? I want it the width of the document
2. It is still behind my image plot, I even tried -/height as I've seen online but same problem!

Comment: make a complete example, that makes it much easier to test. And remove all the unneeded packages. You can use \includegraphics{example-image} as dummy picture if needed.

Comment: "The text should be bigger but without changing the fontsize" \large or \Large, etc. ? "It is still behind my image plot" \AddToShipoutPictureFG?